# How do I transplant walking onion?

Tags: transplanting, propagation, bulbs, onions

I got some [walking onion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_onion) from someone at the community garden, and was wondering if I should take anything into consideration when planting them. There was a little bit of damage to them, and one stem was all present except for a tiny bit holding it together, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I just transplant them as is and that usually works.  Since they will grow from even a small bit of root, and most of the leave removed for cooking, they seem to be pretty resilient.  Some people find that they grow better when planted as a bunch rather than by themselves.

If they get into their second year, I let them flower and keep the seeds to plant from seed.

Answer (score 1):

Shorten their roots and cut from the top about one third from each leaf, then plant them 2-3 cm (1 inch) deeper than they were originally planted. It's best to separate them in March or in September-October keeping a portion of the disc for each fragment separated.